# MySQL spatial query always empty

Tags: mysql, sql, gis, geospatial, spatial

I'm storing geo coordinates in a MySQL table using a spatial index. The problem is that queries where I want to know if a tuple/location is within a bounding box (closed polygon described by 5 coordinates; first an last coordinate are the same) return an empty results. Here's a minimum example that is not working for me as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE osTest(
 loc Point NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX locIndex ON osTest(loc);

-- New York Central Park, The Great Lawn
INSERT INTO osTest (loc) VALUES (POINT(40.781343, -73.966598));
```

If I execute the following table scan query:

```
SELECT AsText(loc), X(loc), Y(loc) FROM osTest;
```

all seems to work fine -- the result looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
| AsText(loc)                 | X(loc)    | Y(loc)     |
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
| POINT(40.781343 -73.966598) | 40.781343 | -73.966598 |
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

However, when I try to execute a query that is using the spatial index, the result is always empty. The polygon the in following polygon describes the whole Central Park:

```
SELECT AsText(loc), X(loc), Y(loc) FROM osTest WHERE WITHIN(loc, GeomFromText('POLYGON(40.800716 -73.958358, 40.796858 -73.949120, 40.764216 -73.973153, 40.768108 -73.981929, 40.800716 -73.958358)') );
```

I've also tried `INTERSECTS`, `OVERLAPS` -- same empty result set. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had an error in my SQL query. It doesn't result in a syntax error, but obviously it doesn't work correctly. More specifically, I had to add additional brackets. I had to change:

```
GeomFromText('POLYGON(40.800716 -73.958358, ...)')
```

to

```
GeomFromText('POLYGON((40.800716 -73.958358, ...))')
```

I simply overlooked it when I searched for examples. And that I didn't get any syntax errors or something didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on mysql GIS, but in postgis the points have to be Latitude,Longitude. My belief is that it is the same in mysql 5.6 GIS data types as well.

According to that theory; in your query, y and x should be switched

Comment: MySQL is agnostic with respect to the "nature" of the coordinates, i.e., it doesn't have to be latitude or longitude. This includes that the order shouldn't matter as long as the order is consistent. I found the problem now: I had an error in my SQL query. See me anser.